# JavaScript Intellisense for classes declared in a self-invoking function does not work in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, jsdoc, code-completion

I would like to use Visual Studio's IntelliSense but it doesn't work in this situation. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
// IntelliSense doesn't work.
Namespace.Class = (function () {
    /** A class. */
    function Class() {
        /** A method. */
        this.method = function () {
            console.log("test 1");
        };
    }
    return Class;
}());

// Intellisense works.
/** A class. */
Namespace2.Class = function () {
    /** A method. */
    this.method = function () {
        console.log("test 2");
    };
};
```

### Examples of what IntelliSense shows

**Not working:**

[image: Doesn't work.]

**Working:**

[image: Works!]

### Notes:

- I can't use a class declaration because of the need to support Internet Explorer.
- JavaScript IntelliSense in Visual Studio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/get-javascript-intellisense-in-visual-studio

Comment: Well, why can't you use what you show as working? That's not a class declaration...

Comment: It is not a self-invoking function and doesn't support the structure we are using. I haven't investigated all the specifics, but the desired flow is a commonly used pattern.

Comment: Thank you for cleaning up the question!

Comment: One thing you might consider is using TypeScript to describe the shape of what you're building, via "d.ts" files ([Declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html)), which Visual Studio will use, but your application may not. If you're not using TypeScript, it may be worth looking into it. You can set the `target` to `"es2015"` and still get JavaScript output that can be used by IE. It may be worth it to suggest to the consumers of this library that they upgrade from IE, considering Microsoft's reduction in support for that platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following snippet. For some unknown reason, Intellisense infers the result of the function as `typeof Class` instead of just `Class`. To fix it typecast the type back to `Class` again.

```js
Namespace.Class = (function () {
  /** A class. */
  function Class() {
    /** A method. */
    this.method = function () {
        console.log("test 1");
    };
  }
  return /** @type {Class} */(/** @type {unknown} */(Class));
}());
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been struggling with this for so long. It will make such a difference to be able to work with intellisense.

Comment: This answer works great for parameters, but when instantiating the class it doesn't identify the type.

e.g.: `var local1_1 = new Namespace.Class();`
Is there an additional attribute I can tag on to help this to work?

Comment: Instead of `/** @type {Namespace.Class} */` define it as `/** @type {typeof Namespace['Class']} */`.